# Dismissing a viewController presented programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Many similar questions already posted, but I cannot seem to find a swift 3/IOS 10 answer. Start a new ViewController with this code ...

```
 self.present(self.myNewVC, animated: true, completion: {                 
                // some more here
            })
        }
```

And close it with this code ...

```
        self.myNewVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.myNewVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.myNewVC.removeFromParentViewController()
```

It works and yet it is still hanging around and when I reopen it without restarting the whole app; I effectively open another on top of the first. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a screenshot from the debugger.

[image]

Comment: it looks like some kind of spike. present and dismiss must be enough, why do you use removeFromSuperview and removeFromParentViewController?

Comment: I guess you just need to dismiss as  `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` instead of   `self.myNewVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Cause when I represent it I see the previously presented one under it in the debugger. I also add a UIView to this VC, would that not also disappear along with the VC.

Comment: Have you tried checking the 'self.presentedViewController' property?

Comment: Found it; was a UIImageView I added to the controller, it dismisses but leaves the stupid UIImageView behind!! Is normal, I don't know, but problem fixed.